# WPF Button Command for right mouse button?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I am learning about MVVM and Commands in WPF. I have a couple of buttons and I want to trigger similar commands depending on the fact if the buttons are clicked with the left or right mouse button.

Until now I used Event Handlers and I was able to determine which mouse button was pressed by checking the MouseButtonEventArgs.

```
<Button Content="Command Test" PreviewMouseDown="Button_PreviewMouseDown"/>
```

Current code behind:

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) {
        Debug.Print("Left");
    }
    else {
        Debug.Print("Right");
    }
}
```

But I don’t see anything similar if I use Commands.

How can I set different commands for a button? One command when the left mouse button is clicked and another command when the right mouse button is clicked?

```
<Button Content="Command Test" Command="{Binding PressLetterCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Currently the Command only fires when the left mouse button is clicked. If the command would also be fired if the right mouse button is clicked and I can find out which button was clicked that would be also a solution.

I searched and I found this question and answer which uses Decorator. [How do I bind a command to e.g. the right mouse button in a ControlTemplate in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976169/how-do-i-bind-a-command-to-e-g-the-right-mouse-button-in-a-controltemplate-in-w) I tried it but as far as I understand this won’t work for my buttons.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A Button is clicked, regardless if it was the left or right mouse button, or the keyboard if it has the focus. That's why it has a single Click event, and a single Command. Don't change this behaviour.

Comment: What's the benefit from changing the standard behavior of the button? How many applications did you see, which has some behavior on right mouse click on buttons?

Comment: @Clemens: I use letter buttons from A to Z to let the user input a little text on a form which is normally only used with the mouse. If the left mouse button is clicked then the letters are uppercase and with the right button they are lower case. This is maybe not perfect but I like it more than an extra Shift Button or 26 more buttons for lower case characters.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this

```
<Button Content="Command Test">
    <Button.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="RightClick" Command="{Binding PressLetterCommand}" />
    </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine. I spend an hour trying this and that and then I get an answer on StackOverflow within 10 minutes. Wonderful!